# I am trying to divide certain rows and columns in a dataframe and end up with the original dataframe but with those new values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the date and prices of different stocks. I am trying to change the values in certain rows and column to adjust for a stock split and end up with the original dataframe but with those new values.

With df.iloc I can get the values that I want, but I cannot fit them as the new values in the same position as they were in the df.

```
import numpy as np                                  
import pandas as pd 

t = pd.DataFrame(index=['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN'])
t['Date_bought']     = ['12/01/2017','12/02/2017','5/04/2018','5/05/2018','12/01/2017','12/02/2017','3/09/2018','12/04/2017']
t['Price_bought']    = [-700.5, -710.2, -126.4, -128.9, -431.2, -433.5, -432.6, -444.0]
t['Date_sold']       = ['5/04/2019','2/05/2018','7/06/2018','8/07/2018','3/08/2018','3/09/2018','12/10/2018','12/11/2018']
t['Price_sold']      = [123.5, 128.1, 117.4, 150.9, 461.2, 430.5, 402.6, 510.0]
t

t[:2, 1] = t.iloc[:2, 1]/7
t
```

The expected results would be to end up with a dataframe with this values.

```
t = pd.DataFrame(index=['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN'])
t['Date_bought']     = ['12/01/2017','12/02/2017','5/04/2018','5/05/2018','12/01/2017','12/02/2017','3/09/2018','12/04/2017']
t['Price_bought']    = [-100.07, -101.45, -126.4, -128.9, -431.2, -433.5, -432.6, -444.0]
t['Date_sold']       = ['5/04/2019','2/05/2018','7/06/2018','8/07/2018','3/08/2018','3/09/2018','12/10/2018','12/11/2018']
t['Price_sold']      = [123.5, 128.1, 117.4, 150.9, 461.2, 430.5, 402.6, 510.0]
t
```

I am getting the following error:
cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: `t.iloc[:2, 1] = t.iloc[:2, 1]/7`?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Just add the `.iloc`:

```
t.iloc[:2,1] = t.iloc[:2,1] / 7
```

```
print(t)

    Date_bought Price_bought    Date_sold   Price_sold
AAPL    12/01/2017  -100.071429 5/04/2019   123.5
AAPL    12/02/2017  -101.457143 2/05/2018   128.1
AAPL    5/04/2018   -126.400000 7/06/2018   117.4
AAPL    5/05/2018   -128.900000 8/07/2018   150.9
AMZN    12/01/2017  -431.200000 3/08/2018   461.2
AMZN    12/02/2017  -433.500000 3/09/2018   430.5
AMZN    3/09/2018   -432.600000 12/10/2018  402.6
AMZN    12/04/2017  -444.000000 12/11/2018  510.0
```

Comment: @RodrigoLask. No problem. Could you "accept" the answer? Would help us both out :)